# AP Statistics Chapter 6 MC Review (TOPIC: Combining Normal Random Variables)

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> 2. “Insert tab A into slot B” is something you might read in the assembly instructions for pre-fabricated bookshelves. Suppose that tab A varies in size according to a Normal distribution with a mean of $30\,\text{mm}$ and a standard deviation of $0.5\,\text{mm}$. The size of slot B is also Normally distributed, with a mean of $32\,\text{mm}$ and a standard deviation of $0.8\,\text{mm}$. The two parts are randomly and independently selected for packaging. What is the probability that tab A won't fit in slot B?
>
>    a.   $0.0007$
>      $\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{\text{b.}}$ $0.0170$
>       c.    $0.0618$
>       d.    $0.9382$
>       e.    $0.9830$

I'm doing AP Statistics, and I'm not sure how to do this type of question. Can someone please explain to me (and anyone who is doing AP Statistics) how to do this question?

Comment: If the random variables are $A$ and $B$ then you want to find $\Pr(A \gt B)$, or in other words  $\Pr(C \lt 0)$ where $C=B-A$.  What do you know about $C$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and adding the image, but I still don't understand how to do the question :P _A_ and _B_ are indeed independent. I do not know anything about C as well, I've tried subtracting the means and SDs of _A_ and _B_ but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you learnt anything about the sum of two normally distributed independent random variables?

Comment: I'm just previewing the chapter ahead of what I am currently on in class

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Henry! I had to **ADD** to get the **DIFFERENCE** of standard deviations! Tricky... tricky.